# Lotus notes date in XML export `20151222T081838,00-05`

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm exporting Notes data with the Java API (I'm using the save as xml function for a document)

My dates are coming out like this:

```
<item name='dat_deleted'>
    <datetime>20151222T081838,00-05</datetime>
</item>
```

What is the `00-05` at the end of the date?  Is that the TZ off set (i.e. this means GMT - 5 hours) or what?

Comment: The format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). And yes, `-05` means 5 hours behind GMT or UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[datetime (Domino DTD)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_DATETIME_ELEMENT_XML.html)

The two digits after the comma (`00`) are hundredths of a second. The `-05` is the offset from UTC. But the time zone offset can be 4 digits -- presumably for zones with offsets in half hour increments, like India.